# Search Mongoose Collection by an Attribute which is an Array of Documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is what the chat model looks like. It has an Array users attribute, with mini user documents as elements.

```
chat: {
    users: [
        {username: "user1", user_id: "1x323x23f23f2cg23", muted: false},
        {username: "user2", user_id: "sdijowd98c23o8h2cg23", muted: false},
    ],
    otherAttributes: undefined
}
```

I want to search through the Chat Mongo collection to pull every conversation that a user is in. This is the gist of what I am trying to do ..

```
Chat.find(users.username.include('user1')), function (err, chats) {
    // work with 'chats' that 'user1' is a part of
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into population?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the username, it is as easy as

```
Chat.find({"users.username":<some username>}, function (err, chats) {

})
```